# What to do with 237 eps files?

Tags: packages, pstricks

I have some 237 `.eps` files that represent the printer's ornaments from the small press `The Underground Grammarian`. I would like to build and provide (to `CTAN`) a package similar to the `pgfornament` package. I'd like to create a command something like `\UGOrnament` which would take either a number or a name as indicated with the accompanying documentation. Other options would basically mirror `\pgfornament`. There are an additional 125 `.tif` files which should be provided as well but I thought I'd start with the `.eps` files first.

So 'What is the problem?' you say. Well as may be apparent, my ambitions are inversely proportional to my TeX-Fu. In a nutshell, I've no clue as to how I'd go about this. Knowing this, I ask the above. I don't want someone to do the work (although I'd not turn it down :) ) but I would appreciate links, suggestions and pointers to guide me. I've a copy of Herbert Voss' ***PSTricks*** and will most likely begin there but I'd like to gather as much information as I can.

I've given some thought to the API hence the reference to `pgfornament`, I've even thought about converting the files to a font or fonts since I have both open source and proprietary software for font creation. I think I'd rather go the `sty` approach instead. Thanks for reading...

Comment: From a packaging point of view, a font would have the great advantage of collecting all the images in a single file. If you build a package on top of the eps files you'd need to distribute all those files with it, probably both in `eps` and `pdf` format. You could still accompany the font with a package selecting the characters.

Comment: Good points all @StephanLehmke although the `pgfornament` package shoves all of it's 196 images into a single .pro file, so the distribution needn't get out of hand file number wise.

Comment: @StephanLehmke come to think of it, if there are sufficient advantages to both approaches I might do both. There are other uses for fonts, i.e. web applications that come to mind.

Comment: Maybe you could add a link to the package you're talking about? I couldn't find `pgfornament` on CTAN and the package [here](http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/pgfornament.zip) contains 89 single pgf files with one ornament each.

Comment: see http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-vectorian It also uses the code of eps images

Comment: @Herbert Thank you! I may have confused the command name with the package name or some such...

Comment: @StephanLehmke See http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: The very package of my confusion ;) They are related and I have used both---they say short term memory is the first to go---I don't know, can't remember!

Comment: If the package you want to imitate is a PSTricks package, then a font is clearly superiour because it'll also work with `pdftex`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pst-vectorian` works in the same way. The code of the eps images was saved in a file `pst-vectorian.pro` (PostScript prologue file):

```
% PostScript prologue for psvectorian.tex.
% Version 0.03, 2011/11/05
%
/tx@vectorianDict 410 dict def
%
tx@vectorianDict begin
/vec1 {
1 setlinejoin
newpath
109.8516 58.404 moveto 
102.7108 70.7583 88.4258 67.3824 82.4704 64.0235 curveto 
76.5236 60.6518 72.9472 60.6518 69.3794 75.2496 curveto 
[...]
119.3743 21.3326 136.0503 48.2933 136.0503 48.2933 curveto 
119.3867 44.9173 116.9958 46.0498 109.8516 58.404 curveto 
closepath 
fill 
} def
%
/vec2 {
[...]
closepath
fill
} def
...
```

from within `pst-vectorian.sty` the PostScript functions are called as `vec1`, `vec2`, a.s.o. with the possibility to change the font color.

Comment: The files I have were all created in Adobe Freestyle quite some years ago. Do I analyze the included dictionary throw out the un-necessary and proceed, or leave a single inclusion and then concatenate the eps files minus duplicate information? What about bounding box info?

Comment: @hsmyers: analyze the dictionary and delete all what's not important for the code. A bounding box is not needed for an ornament which often is placed over some already given text area. `pst-vectorian` uses `\rput`. See the code of the documentation.

Comment: I've had some initial success using eps2eps on the source. That said I wonder if the following is necessary: `cleartomark end end pagesave restore
     showpage
    %%PageTrailer
    %%Trailer
    %%Pages: 1` at the end of the file?

Comment: @hsmyers: no that is all not important

Answer (score 10):

I believe that `.pro` is a good way to go. However, many people use pdfLaTeX and they might like to benefit from your package, too. I therefore suggest converting all the files to `.pdf` as well (e.g. by `epstopdf`), and then merging them in a single file (using `pdftk`). The exact syntax to merge all `ornament-*.pdf` files in one file is

```
pdftk ornament-*.pdf cat output allornanements.pdf
```

Your package could then have a `pdf` and `ps` options that would switch between the PS loading command and the PDF one, that looks like

```
\includegraphics[page=#1]{allornaments.pdf}
```

Comment: This would have the advantage of being almost immediately do-able and testable. I think it could also be folded into the final solution.

Comment: There's a way how to recognize whether the user invoked `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex` or `latex`, which you could use to fit in the right option in case none is given. I'm just sorry that I don't remember how to do it :-/

Comment: @tohecz and @hsmyers `\ifpdf`, `\ifluatex`, `\ifxetex`. See also packages `iftex`, `ifpdf`, `ifluatex` and `ifxetex`.

Comment: @Speravir thanks for the reminder. Tohecz I'm going ahead with your idea in parallel with the other approaches---thanks!